# How to find native memory leak in .net application?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, profiling

I have application written in C#. Memory usage shows that there is a memory leak. However, dotTrace shows that managed memory is OK, so I think that leak occurs in native memory (yes, there are some native calls in my application). How can I find the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: how can you see memory leak when dotTrace says it is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a memory dump of the running application, and then use **[Windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx)** or **[Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx)** to investigate the issue.

Related resources:

- [How to research unmanaged memory leaks in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850098/how-to-research-unmanaged-memory-leaks-in-net)
- [Windbg on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDbg)
- [Analysing dump files with Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx)